# How do I install Crystal Reports on my PC? It's giving an error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports

Helo. I have downloaded crystal reports from the SAP website. I have VS 2012 installed on my system.

Whenever i run the MSI file, it gives an error saying that:

"Visual Studio 2010 is needed"

Why am i getting this error?

Please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably installed an old version.  Here is the download link for the many different builds of the install:

http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824

Also, as noted on the page, you will want to run the EXE installer and not the MSI if you want it to integrate with Visual Studio (2010, 2012 or 2013).  This also means if you upgrade to Visual Studio 2013 in the future you will probably need to re-run the installer if you want to see it's components in VS.